# IBM Sterling file transfer

Tags: sftp, file-transfer, ibm-sterling

We recently moved to use IBM Sterling. I went through some features of it and got to know that, it can do file transfer (SSH) to either Windows or Linux. So I asked Sterling team to transfer file as soon as vendor sends it. But I'm getting pushed back from the team saying it's not best practice for Sterling to push files rather your application should pull it. I couldn't find anything on these lines. Can someone comment please?

Update:

Sterling team said, you need to have a SSH tool (Solar Winds) installed on windows box in-order for Sterling to push files and it can degrade performance of the windows machine. Can't agree to it.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Sterling B2B Integrator can act as an SFTP server as well as an SFTP client.

SFTP server howto?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3JSW_5.2.0/com.ibm.help.svcs_adpts_m_z.doc/SFTP_Server_adapter_v526.html

SFTP client howTO?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3JSW_5.2.0/com.ibm.help.svcs_adpts_m_z.doc/SFTP_Client_adapter.html

If you want your B2B Integrator to act as a an SFTP server you will need an SFTP client installed on the remote machine. And if you want your B2B Integrator to act as an SFTP client you will need to install an SFTP server on your remote machine.